# How do I use an existing view with reverse()?

Tags: python, django, url, reverse

I created a view that handle POST. I'm trying to use reverse to create a view that uses this view to process multiple jobs. I get the following

Below is error message

> django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'release_action'
>   with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s)
>   tried: []

View code that handles POST requests.

```
class ReleaseActionView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser)

    def post(self, request, release_id, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    return Response(...)
```

I wrote the code in reverse () to run the above code in the for loop. I get an error message. What is the problem? Here is for-loop code

```
class ReleaseBulkActionView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        for release in releases:
        ...
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('release_action', args=(), kwargs={}))
```

Urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^releases/(?P<release_id>[0-9]+)/actions/?$', ReleaseActionView.as_view(), name="release_action")
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Your ReleaseActionView quite clearly does take args, so why are you passing empty ones?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman In the above ReleaseActionView, args and kwargs do not receive arguments.

Comment: @Exprator error message: django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'release_action' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: yes because you are  not passing any args and kwargs during reverse

Comment: @Exprator In ReleaseActionView post method get request and release_id as so I do not pass any args and kwargs. Is it wrong?

Comment: But you have written your URL so that ReleaseActionView *does* take arguments. And then you attempt to create a URL without those arguments. Why is that not clear?

Comment: you need to pass the release_id as args to the view or you need to change the url

Answer (score 4):

Your are missing the arguments in `reverse()` I think. It might be :

```
release_id = 4711
reverse('release_action', kwargs={'release_id': release_id,})
```

would get you an url for 4711